# What is the name of this finite group of order 36

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In my research we find a finite group of order 36, which satisfies the following generating relations

\begin{equation}
\langle g_{12}~,~g_3 ~|~g_{12}^{12}=e=g_3^3, ~~~g_{12}~g_3=g_3^2~g_{12}\rangle
\end{equation}

So I am wondering what is the name of this group? Does any one also know some references on its representations? Thank you!

Comment: Looks like the dihedral group $D_{18}$, the group of symmetries of the octodecagon.

Comment: @Bernard It doesn't look like that to me. It has no element of order $18$. Not all groups have names. The structure description (by GAP) is "C3 x (C3 : C4)".

Comment: Thank you guys! A name is not really important, I am just curious.

Comment: @Derek Holt: You're certainly right. Out of curiosity: what do you denote C3:C4?

Comment: Generally speaking, : denotes a semi-direct product. In this particular case, C3:C4 is the dicyclic group of order 12.